# How to plot against scaled axes?

Tags: plotting, visualization, labeling

Say I have some plot, such as:

```
Plot[Exp[-(x - 2)^2/(2*1^2)], {x, 0, 6}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

But I want to present it with the axis labeled as some scalar of a constant amount.

Suppose x represents a physical quantity (e.g. distance) and X=3.1 meters is a fundamental distance in this problem.

How can I change the axes in the plot so that the labels represent the value "x" in terms of "X"?

In other words, I would like for the plot to remain the same, but the previous location of the "1" tick would become ~0.323 (since 0.323*3.1 ~ 1), or a new "1" tick would appear slightly past the original location of the "3" tick.

How can I accomplish this (without changing the plot itself, only the axes representation).

Comment: Tick labeling is particularly annoying in *Mathematica*, which is why I would suggest scaling `x` in your function instead. So, do `Plot[Exp[-(3.1*x - 2)^2/(2*1^2)], {x, 0, 6/3.1}]`.

Answer (score 4):

```
Plot[
 Exp[-(x - 2)^2/(2*1^2)], {x, 0, 6},
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{#, # .323}] &[Range@6], Automatic},
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the rescaled plot to show its x-axis ticks with normal *Mathematica* style divisions rather than have ticks that are multiples of the scale factor. It takes a little more work to do it that way, but I think it is worth the extra effort.

Here is one way it can be done.

```
f[x_] := Exp[-(x - 2)^2/(2*1^2)]

With[{scaleFactor = .323, xmin = 0, xmax = 6},
  Module[{divisions, xticks},
    divisions = 
      FindDivisions[scaleFactor {xmin, xmax}, {Ceiling[scaleFactor xmax], 5}];
    xticks = Transpose[{# /scaleFactor, #}]&[N[Union @@ divisions[[2]]]];
    Plot[f[x], {x, xmin, xmax},
      PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, .2}, Automatic},
      Ticks -> {xticks, Automatic},
      AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"},
      Epilog -> {Red, Line[{{3, 0}, {3, f[3]}}]}]]]
```

[image: plot]

As you can see from the vertical red line, the unscaled value of `x = 3` falls very close to the scaled value 1 as expected.